# Method onComplete doesn't work

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Im trying to make an app for android. 
The app must have a login and register form and I can't understand why method onComplete doesn't work but data is added to the database in register page. 
Here is the code :

```
private void submitForm(String email, String password){
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(RegisterActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    FirebaseAuthException e = (FirebaseAuthException)task.getException();
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Registration successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
                        finish();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "" +e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
}

private void validate(String email, String password, String confirmPassword){
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
        if (android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
            if ((!TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) && (!TextUtils.isEmpty(confirmPassword))) {
                if (!password.equals(confirmpassword)) {
                    if(password.length() > 6){
                        submitForm(email, password);
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Password must be at least 6 characters.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Passwords do not match.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please fill in both password fields.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter a valid email address.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please fill the email field.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    email = findViewById(R.id.emailEditText);
    password = findViewById(R.id.passwordEditText);
    confirmpassword = findViewById(R.id.confirmpasswordEditText);
    register = findViewById(R.id.registerbutton);

    register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            validate(email.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString(), confirmpassword.getText().toString());
        }
    });
}
```

When I add data to the database I expect to be trown on login page.

Comment: Is there any exception are you getting ?

Comment: `finish()` here is the problem

Comment: @JaiminModi yes: E/StorageHelpers: Failed to turn object into JSON
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'org.json.JSONObject com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzm.zzbf()' on a null object reference

Comment: @KopiBryant no, i already removed it and nothing happens :(

Comment: Which firebse version are you using?

Comment: @buzzingsilently implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.1.0'

Comment: something there remains uninitialized.

Comment: i did a exact program like you, however i put my register code in the `onClick` method instead of calling method and its work as well. You can consider about it. however what message did you get i mean Toast message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While updating Firebase to latest version make sure you **update your google play services** also.

In my case with Firebase 15+ I had to set google play service (in project gradle)

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.1'
```

Also try **clear data** & **re-install** app options.

Comment: Please up-vote this answer, If helped. Happy Coding!